# How do I store multiple variables in a single session?

Tags: php, arrays, session, while-loop

This is what I have, what do I do? I want to store two variables in a single session, they are username and avatar.

```
if ($count == 1) 
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//while ($_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'])
$_SESSION['users'] = [''];
$_SESSION['users']['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['users']['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];

{
session_start();
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you can't use:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
```

Comment: How would it be placed in the while loop? I thought you had to use an array.

Comment: Hi @GarrettRobertson, `$_SESSION[]` *is* an array. If you already know all of the keys you will use in the array, you don't need a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

First: Use session_start(); of the top of your code.

Second: What you mean with this row? "$_SESSION['users'] = [''];"
If you want to initialize it you should use:

```
$_SESSION['users'] = array();
```

In short your code should like:

```
session_start();
.
.
.
if ($count == 1) 
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['users'] = array();
$_SESSION['users']['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['users']['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but how would this fit into a while loop? This is the user logging in.

Comment: Also, how this appear when requested on other pages?

Comment: What is the main idea of this?

Comment: So the username AND avatar can be grabbed from the session and placed on the page where I want it to be. All I need to know now is how all of that fits into the while loop and how I would display it on the page. would it be $_SESSION['username'] or something else?

Comment: I don't understand the need for loop. Loop of what? If you try to find some user by username it's not good idea to get all the users from db and loop over them to find the desired username. Instead use sql statement to do that.

Comment: This is how I have always done it. Can you fix it for me? http://pastebin.com/kvjdNLPX

Comment: SELECT username, avatar,... FROM your_user_table WHERE username='theusername' AND password='password'; This will return result for user and password. If no rows returned then the login is incorrect. If more than one row is returned then you have data mess.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11719/discussion-between-bksi-and-garrett-robertson)